# Not able to get tap points from tapjoy offerwall?

Tags: android, tapjoy

I have developed an android app. In this app I have integrated `tapjoy` and `everbadge offerwalls`. In tapjoy offerwall, I am calling following method to show offerwall.

```
TapjoyConnect.getTapjoyConnectInstance().showOffers();
```

but when I complete an offer I am not able to see tap points in toast. following is the code I have written for `tapjoy offerwall`.

```
public class TapjoyOfferwall implements TapjoyEarnedPointsNotifier, TapjoyNotifier{

    private Activity context;
    //private AppPreferences appPreferences;

    private String AppId_TapJoy = "bba49f11-b87f-4c0f-9632-21aa810dd6f1";
    private String SecretKey_TapJoy = "yiQIURFEeKm0zbOggubu";

    private String displayText = "";
    boolean update_text = false;
    boolean earnedPoints = false;

    int point_total;
    String currency_name;





    public TapjoyOfferwall(Activity context) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        //appPreferences = new AppPreferences(context);

        // Enables logging to the console.
        TapjoyLog.enableLogging(true);

        // OPTIONAL: For custom startup flags.
        Hashtable<String, String> flags = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        flags.put(TapjoyConnectFlag.ENABLE_LOGGING, "true");

        // Connect with the Tapjoy server. Call this when the application first starts.
        // REPLACE THE APP ID WITH YOUR TAPJOY APP ID.
        // REPLACE THE SECRET KEY WITH YOUR SECRET KEY.
        TapjoyConnect.requestTapjoyConnect(context,AppId_TapJoy, SecretKey_TapJoy,flags);
        //TapjoyConnect.getTapjoyConnectInstance().setUserID(""+appPreferences.GetUserID());

        // Set our earned points notifier to this class.
        TapjoyConnect.getTapjoyConnectInstance().setEarnedPointsNotifier(this);
        //LaunchTapJoyOfferwall();
    }

    @Override
    public void earnedTapPoints(int amount)
    {
        earnedPoints = true;
        update_text = true;
        displayText = "You've just earned " + amount + " Tap Points!";

        // We must use a handler since we cannot update UI elements from a different thread.
        System.out.println("displayText :: "+displayText);
        OEPUtil.showAppToast(context, displayText);
    }

    public void LaunchTapJoyOfferwall() {
        TapjoyConnect.getTapjoyConnectInstance().showOffers();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void SetBannerAutoRefresh() {
        TapjoyConnect.getTapjoyConnectInstance().enableBannerAdAutoRefresh(false);
    }

    public void SetShutDown() {
        TapjoyConnect.getTapjoyConnectInstance().sendShutDownEvent();
    }
}
```

this class I am accessing in one of my activity class on click of a button.

Please let me know whatever I am doing is correct or not and how can I get points??

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you come up with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you..

http://www.jjask.com/32814/android-tapjoy-offerwall-never-makes-callback

basically

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    TapjoyConnect.getTapjoyConnectInstance().getTapPoints(this);
    super.onResume();
}
```